# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_package'. Airflow not find my_package in its Python environment

Tags: python-3.x, airflow, airflow-taskflow

I set up my DAG in docker container as follows:

```
with DAG(
    "my_dag",
    default_args=dag_config,
    schedule="@weekly",
) as dag:

    config_env = BashOperator(
        task_id="config_env",
        bash_command="cd /opt/airflow/include/my_package && python -m pip install -e .",
    )

    @task()
    def get_my_function():
        from my_package import my_function

        my_function()
```

When running this DAG, it returns

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_package'
```

However, if I go into the docker container using Python shell do the import, it works with no problem.

```
from my_package import my_function
```

which suggest that my_package is successfully installed in the environment.

I also checked if Python shell and airflow is using the same Python enviroment.
For Python shell, I use `which python`.

For Airflow DAG, I modified the task as follows:

```
@task()
def get_my_function():]
    import sys

    print("Python Executable Path:", sys.executable)
    print("Python Version:", sys.version)
    print("sys.path:", sys.path)

    from my_package import my_fucntion
```

Python Executable are the same `/usr/local/bin/python`. I also tried to use `PythonOperator` instead of taskFlow API. The same error returns.

- Airflow 2.5.1
- Python 3.9

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Airflow cannot find package source in the `./lib/site-packages` path. Problem solved by adding the source package code into `sys.path`, i.e.,

in airflow dag, write following:

```
import sys

sys.path.append("/opt/airflow/include/my_package/src")

with DAG(
    "my_dag",
    default_args=dag_config,
    schedule="@weekly",
) as dag:

    config_env = BashOperator(
        task_id="config_env",
        bash_command="cd /opt/airflow/include/my_package && python -m pip install -e .",
    )

    @task()
    def get_my_function():
        from my_package import my_function

        my_function()
```